# Error after running yum update mysql

Tags: mysql, redhat, yum

I have a redhat linux server.

I ran `yum update mysql` and it worked fine.
The problem is that when I went to phpMyAdmin all of the databases were deleted.
So I used "import" to import the database which I backed up before the process, but in the middle I got an error saying "primary key duplication" (though I could not find it in the file).

phpMyAdmin listed all tables created until that point. When I used `SELECT * FROM table_which_caused_error` query, I got all rows even though this table wasn't listed in the tables list. However, when I tried to run "DROP TABLE table_which_caused_error" I got an error saying "table does not exist".

What can be wrong??

Thanks,

Joel

Comment: Are the tables/databases present when you use `mysqladmin`?

Comment: @TiZon  - No, they are not there as well

Comment: (but when using SELECT, it does return rows from the table)

Comment: Restart mysql server and check if the tables exist.

Comment: It seems that your data directory is not consistent with the mysql database (system database). Are you using Innodb or MyISAM?

Answer (score 0):

mysql_upgrade  needs to be run after upgrading mysql.  In CentOS and the remi version of mysql, it is not added to the rpm post processing as far as i can tell.  Of course, you want to see if /etc/init.d/mysqld restart && /etc/init.d/httpd restart helps as well.

man mysql_upgrade:

mysql_upgrade examines all tables in all databases for incompatibilities with the current version of MySQL Server.  mysql_upgrade also upgrades the system tables so that you can take advantage of new privileges or capabilities that might have been added.

mysql_upgrade should be executed each time you upgrade MySQL. It supersedes the older
mysql_fix_privilege_tables script, which has been removed in MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin , in Settings tab, you can try checking the following values:

Settings -> SQL Queries -> Ignore multiple statement errors If you are using CSV format:

Settings -> Import -> CSV -> Do not abort on INSERT error If you are using SQL format:

Settings -> Export -> SQL -> Use ignore inserts

you use my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990908/mysql-weird-issue-while-importing-a-large-file-duplicate-entry-for-key-primary/25582497#25582497) with details